# Importing a .pyd (created with SWIG) in Python 2.7.3 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, import, swig

I have created a .pyd file with SWIG under Windows named (_example.pyd).

I am able to send the file to my email and import it with another Windows machine using the same version of Python (Python 2.7.3) with this simple command:

```
.>>> import _example

.>>>
```

But when I send it to my email and tried to import the file with a Mac, I get:

```
"No module named _example"
```

Any ideas?

In both cases, I saved the file into the Python path.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Python extensions (.pyd files) are essentially DLLs.
If you want to use your extension on a Mac, you will need to compile it for/on a Mac.

http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll

Comment: Oh no! Is there the Mac equivalent for a Windows .pyd file? I spent a really long time finding out how to create a C/C++ extension through SWIG on Windows so If I can create an extension on Windows for the Mac, then that'd be great.

Comment: @user1449530 MacOS has .dynlib files that are like .so or .dll files. You'll want to build one of those instead.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same error for a different reason: I had built the module from source, except I assumed **".pyd"** to be a universal extension (be it a DLL or an ELF shared object), so I told gcc to create "mymodule.pyd" instead of "mymodule.so": on both Linux and Windows, the contents of the file were correct once compiled, but the name was only valid on Windows.

On Linux, a simple `mv mymodule.pyd mymodule.so` solved it.