# Are SWIG generated wrappers portable?

Tags: c, python-3.x, swig

The SWIG program generates a wrapper to interface with C code, in this case, Python. While the compiled C code it interfaces with is obviously not portable, would the SWIG Python wrapper itself be? Would I be able to only once generate this wrapper and ship it with my code, or would the end user need to regenerate the SWIG wrapper code during their build procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the end users have the same OS, I think they are portable. As I understand it, you just need the example.pyd and example.py file for the SWIG portion. 
At least on my machine, if I move those files to a different folder,I can import and run the module fine. Do not need the source .c, _wrap.c, or .i files.

[Importing a .pyd (created with SWIG) in Python 2.7.3 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866288/importing-a-pyd-created-with-swig-in-python-2-7-3-on-mac)

I think within the UNIX OS (Linux and MacOS), it might be still okay. But the person in the link (second answer) is saying that pyd is only for windows. So then the end user might have to re-compile things.

I guess one more thing to consider is 32 bit vs. 64 bit. I have no idea about this.

Comment: Given that the individual OS may require different wrappers, would you think that having a different wrapper for different OS would be a good approach for shipping out a package?

Comment: I am not sure about shipping out a package because I am in academia and people usually let endusers to compile in case they need to. I noticed that for Matlab, people do put makefiles on github so that endusers can compile mex files (c /c++ extension for matlab) works for differently for unix vs. windows (e.g., makefiles('windows')). I guess you could make an instruction for installing swig and including it in the environment variable as well as making setup.py that people can run? For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239473/building-a-module-with-setuptools-and-swig

Comment: I guess it is the same for swig/python; people put makefile code to make sure that endusers can compile. This is one of the many examples on the SWIG master github: https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Examples/python/simple

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking, using CMake to actually compile the code. I'm hesitant to require SWIG given that it's a dependency needed to install the code. Although, if you think about it, it's no so different to requiring GCC or some other compiler. Thanks for the info!